# invalid label error executing processTemplate for jTemplate

Tags: jquery, label, jtemplate

I am getting an "invalid label" error that references jtemplates.js.  If I comment out the line with processTemplate, it goes away.  I can even do an alert, at that point, on result.d.

Here is my AJAX call:

```
var data = { ID: @SessionVariables.ID };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Services/DataService.asmx/FetchProfitSummaryData",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, status) {
            $('#rptProfitSummary').setTemplateURL('../Investment/JTemplates/TestListTemplate.htm');
            $('#rptProfitSummary').processTemplate(result.d);
       },
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
```

My template content is bare bones:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>JTemplate basic success!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It does not seem to be related to JSON vs JSONP, or validation issues, as I have been seeing in other questions.  I'm also using jquery 1.7, so a bug from using a version earlier than that also is not the problem.

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error is misleading. It really has nothing to do with any labels.  What I had overlooked was that the path to the template is incorrect. Instead of

```
'../Investment/JTemplates/TestListTemplate.htm'
```

it should be

```
'../JTemplates/TestListTemplate.htm'.
```